# Cordova facebook OAuth login issue

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-login

I am trying to use facebook oauth in phonegap app http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/

but the issue is my redirect url will be like "file:///" which doesn't seem to be working.
It opens the facebook blank window.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to explicitly specify the redirect URL in the FBInit(). Just pass the FB App id. The default redirection url is https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html. Add this in your redirection url in FB app Advanced settings.

Importantly make sure you add the inappbrowser core plugin:
cordova plugins add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

vou have to specify some dumy URL or localhost for `redirect_uri` and it will work.

Here is facebook oauth example for phonegap:
https://github.com/krisrak/jquery-cordova-oauth2

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this library http://adodson.com/hello.js/#hellojs
, which allows you to specify your re-direct url.
It would be useful in case you have a server and want to know when a user login using your app.
It also seems that if your re-direct url is `http://localhost/anything.html` you do not even need to have it configured in Facebook. Feels like a bug.